# How to reverse engineer Linux password?

Tags: linux, passwords, raspberry-pi, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer the password to my Raspberry Pi. The username and password is already public (`pi:raspberry`) so this is just to learn how password on Linux works and if it is even possible. What would be the steps to perform to make this possible? This is what I got so far.

**/etc/passwd**

```
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
```

**/etc/shadow**

```
pi:$6$kfePYuOk$0Iyzi5arkBfi8/FhDCKyEZ.nN77Jd.JdnIJqBFcD/QfZrruFzTu9PHit3J7qROeMPrZL9QgoP/W1XtwOpnPFM/:15689:0:99999:7:::
```

From the shadow file we can see that the hashing function is SHA-512 (`$6`), the salt is `kfePYuOk` and the hashed password is `0Iyzi5arkBfi8/FhDCKyEZ.nN77Jd.JdnIJqBFcD/QfZrruFzTu9PHit3J7qROeMPrZL9QgoP/W1XtwOpnPFM/`

### Update

I realize that hashing is one way but theoretically you could try hash all string and look at the result. So I guess what I'm really after is how does Linux go from the password `raspberry` to `0Iyzi5arkBfi8/FhDCKyEZ.nN77Jd.JdnIJqBFcD/QfZrruFzTu9PHit3J7qROeMPrZL9QgoP/W1XtwOpnPFM/`.

Comment: You realise that a hash is not the same as encryption, right?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the hash... Because by definition you can't.  It's a one-way hash not a two way encryption.

Comment: I realize this, see update.

Comment: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

Comment: @Matthew Thanks! This was clearly more advanced than just sha512(password+salt) that I had in mind. But now I am closer to understand how it works.

Comment: Crypt-C is intentionally designed to allow for multiple ciphers, slowdown brute force attacks and reduce the ability to use collisions to hack passwords.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: Hash algorithms are one-way by design, not by definition. A poor hash algorithm can be reversed. (For example, an md5sum is 128 bits, but I understand there are ways to guess the input in far less than 2**128 tries.)

Comment: Dictionary attacks are a common approach. A password like `raspberry` is much easier to crack than one of the same length like `vtexzocfamn` or `%CSL-bk$R3=`. If your password is a correctly spelled English dictionary word, an attacker manages to get a copy of the hash can break it quickly.

Comment: Brute force, rainbow tables and collisions are not reversing a hash.  They are exploiting weak cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-512 is a cryptographic hash,  a one way function. Many possible inputs have the same hash, yet finding one is computationally prohibitively expensive.

Yes, you can try many inputs until you find a match but that will take millions of years with current computers.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain deeper, Hashing is a one way "messing" works almost like this:

Assuming password being "1234" and [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) "2" the sum of the password digits would be 10

```
passwordsum * salt + 1= hash
```

your hash would be 21, so you see that even if you reverse the equation, you can't just recover the original password, what you can make to get this password is making a bruteforce to try to find the password.

Having the hash and the salt you can make a software that puts your bruteforce data and salt on a SHA-512 algorithm
to try to find a [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29) or maybe the password.